# Lua Language MySQL: Error in my file, ipairs

Tags: mysql, lua, lua-table

i have a problam in my LUA Script, i'm trying to make a new server on MTA Game Servers, and using in my script a LUA Langauge but i have a console error and don't know how to repair it

The Consle Error

[File.lua 117 Line Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X0f2.png) And The File Code

```
--The main function to open the entire advertisements system.
function openAdvertisements( player, command ) local advertisements = { } --These will hold our advertisements to send to the client and populate our advertisement tables.
if not player then player = source end

--Fetch all of the advertisements from the database

for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do
    if tonumber( ad.expiry ) >= tonumber( getRealTime().timestamp ) then --Check if the advertisement has expired, delete it if so.
        ad.author = exports.mysql:select_one( "characters", { id = ad.created_by } ).charactername
        table.insert( advertisements, ad )
    else
        deleteAdvertisement( ad.id )
    end
end

triggerClientEvent( player, resourceName .. ":display_all", root, `advertisements, exports.integration:isPlayerAdmin( player ) ) --Send the` `advertisements to the client to create the GUI.`
```

The Line 117 Error:
for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do

Comment: do a "print(exports.mysql:select('advertisements'))" to see what value is returning from that cmd. From your console image, it appears that cmd is not working as you expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388448/bad-argument-1-to-ipairs-table-expected-got-boolean)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This .**

```lua
database = dbConnect( "mysql", "dbname=databasename;host=1.2.3.4;charset=utf8", "username", "password" )
function getData()
    local result = {}
    local query = dbQuery(database, "select * from advertisements")
    result = dbPoll(query,-1)
    dbFree(query)
if #result > 0 then
        return result
    else    
        return {}
    end
end

--The main function to open the entire advertisements system.
function openAdvertisements( player, command ) local advertisements = { } --These will hold our advertisements to send to the client and populate our advertisement tables.
if not player then player = source end

--Fetch all of the advertisements from the database

for _, ad in ipairs( getData() ) do
    if tonumber( ad.expiry ) >= tonumber( getRealTime().timestamp ) then --Check if the advertisement has expired, delete it if so.
        ad.author = exports.mysql:select_one( "characters", { id = ad.created_by } ).charactername
        table.insert( advertisements, ad )
    else
        deleteAdvertisement( ad.id )
    end
end

triggerClientEvent( player, resourceName .. ":display_all", root, `advertisements, exports.integration:isPlayerAdmin( player ) ) --Send the` `advertisements to the client to create the GUI.`
```