# bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got boolean)

Tags: mysql, lua

console error;

```
117: call: failed to call 'mysql:select' [string "?"]
117: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' <table expected, got boolean>
```

the function;

```
function openAdvertisements( player, command )
    local advertisements = { } --These will hold our advertisements to send to the client and populate our advertisement tables.

    if not player then player = source end

    --Fetch all of the advertisements from the database
    for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do
        if tonumber( ad.expiry ) >= tonumber( getRealTime().timestamp ) then --Check if the advertisement has expired, delete it if so.
            ad.author = exports.mysql:select_one( "characters", { id = ad.created_by } ).charactername
            table.insert( advertisements, ad )
        else
            deleteAdvertisement( ad.id )
        end
    end

    triggerClientEvent( player, resourceName .. ":display_all", root, advertisements, exports.integration:isPlayerAdmin( player ) ) --Send the advertisements to the client to create the GUI.
end
```

line 117; 
for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do
leaveCs(cid)

Comment: I've solved the second problem by change the 
`exports.mysql:select('advertisements')` to `mysql:query("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1")` and the first consle error has changed to `117: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' <table expected, got number>`

Answer (score 1):

When
  `exports.mysql:select('advertisements')` failed return `boolean` and you can't use `ipairs` on `boolean` value because `ipairs` can use with tables.

And why `exports.mysql:select('advertisements')` failed to call?

because 
put quotes around tables, for they are not strings
and should do that like

```
exports.mysql:select("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE <something>")
```

Comment: I've solved the second problem by change the 
`exports.mysql:select('advertisements')` to `mysql:query("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1")` and the first consle error has changed to `117: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' <table expected, got number>`

Comment: Do
print(exports.mysql:select("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1"))
and say what you see

Comment: consle output: false

Comment: exports.mysql:select("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE <something>")  in here have problem. I need to know type of mysql and exports but what can say for here when use select then query it's maybe a wrong