# bad argument #1 to 'ipa [ irs' (table expected, got boolean)

Tags: mysql, lua

i get this error on console
advertisements/advertisements.lua:117: bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got boolean)
and this
advertisements/advertisements.lua:117: call: failed to call 'mysql:select' [string "?"]

function openAdvertisements( player, command )
    local advertisements = { } --These will hold our advertisements to send to the client and populate our advertisement tables.

```
if not player then player = source end

--Fetch all of the advertisements from the database
for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do
    if tonumber( ad.expiry ) >= tonumber( getRealTime().timestamp ) then --Check if the advertisement has expired, delete it if so.
        ad.author = exports.mysql:select_one( "characters", { id = ad.created_by } ).charactername
        table.insert( advertisements, ad )
    else
        deleteAdvertisement( ad.id )
    end
end

triggerClientEvent( player, resourceName .. ":display_all", root, advertisements, exports.integration:isPlayerAdmin( player ) ) --Send the advertisements to the client to create the GUI.
```

end

this is the line 117
for _, ad in ipairs( exports.mysql:select('advertisements') ) do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bad argument #1 to 'ipairs' (table expected, got boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388448/bad-argument-1-to-ipairs-table-expected-got-boolean)

Comment: it's not helping me , but thank you

Comment: The answer is actually in the comment of the first answer; the first person was able to resolve it. Have you tried that?

Comment: i maked this but not work look 
for _, ad in ipairs(exports.mysql:select("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1")) do